# Audio signal series' beginning points (about 50) distort after a bandpass filter

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, finite-impulse-response, bandpass, butterworth

I am using some bandpass filters to detect a certain frequency of the sampled audio series in noisy environment. Everything is OK except this:
I found that for many bandpass filters I tried(butterworth, window based FIR etc.) The audio signals' beginning points(about 50~100) always distort after the filter.

For example:
[image]

I am new to DSP so maybe I didn't express in an scientific way... **What I mean by "distortion" is that in some cases these beginning points should have been filtered out but they were not, and in other cases vice versa**.After these distorted points, everything becomes fine...
Could u plz help me on this issue?
Thank you very much[image]

To make this question more clear, below is a plot consists of 2 waveforms, the blue one is the original audio signal sampled, and the brown one is the sampled signal passed butterworth filter.It doesn't like filter delay stuff.[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's the filter's output **transient**, whose length is dependent on the effective length of the filter impulse response. If you are performing block based filtering, then only the very first block should exhibit it and later subsequent blocks should not display this transient, due to properly set initial values.

Comment: Thank u, u pointed a right direction for me...is there a way to eliminate the transient effect?(or minimize it) cuze' ideally I wanna keep every point in my sampled signal

Comment: a short transient requires a short impulse response. You cannot completely eliminate it, especially when the signal is *suddenly* applied. But as I said, only the first block will have it and later blocks will be ok.

Comment: 2 ways (at least) to remove initial transient: Start sampling that much earlier, before you need data, and discard transient portion after filtering.  Filter the data backwards in time.

Comment: @hotpaw2 thanks for reminding the methods. The first is a *practical* one (that several variants of it can be used). I was more inclined on an explanation of what was happening at the beginnning portion of the filter output. There's still a transient there but it's not what we care practically. The forward backward (zero phase) filtering requires a noncausal (offline) application if its not a matter. In addition the magnitude response should be carefully designed to match the original filter's response. The transient is not eliminated but the *central* portion of the output is taken.

Comment: Thank you for u 2, actually my filtering is real-time, so I have to give up IIR and use FIR instead? ( Real-time means that after a block of sampled data comes, I need to do an immediate filtering and do other calculations when I am waiting for another block of data to come)

Comment: real-time can be done both with FIR or IIR filters. But you need to consider response time vs computational complexity issues, in addition to transients. Please search the site for such questions.

Comment: U mentioned the "offline" application, does that mean filtering after finishing the whole process of sampling(In this way u can discard the very beginning part)? But for my case, for every time of filtering, ideally I want to keep all the data which passed the filter, is it possible?

Comment: All "real-time" filters, other than flat, have a transient delay.

Comment: Now I switch from IIR to FIR, due to FIR's finite impulse response, I am looking for a filter in FIR which has: short transient time; good bandpass filtering performance and relatively low order for MCU to compute. Am I doing the right way? are there some good filters u recommend? Thank you very much